# Vector with prime notation intuitive explanation?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, electromagnetism

This is said to be the equation to find the electric field for a continuous distribution of charges:
[image: Div Grad Curl and All That - I-7]

Just starting to learn calc III, I'm not exactly sure how to interpret this. I've never seen the prime notation paired with a vector like this before. What, geometrically does each symbol represent? I understand well electromagnetism and how Coulomb's Law and Gauss' Law apply intuitively, but the fact that the unit vector is a function multiplied by the charge density of a function, I'm really confused by. Especially because I thought $\rho$ was a function of $(x,y,z)$. I'm trying to get a grasp of the idea behind this rather than a necessarily mathematically rigorous definition of what's happening.

Comment: Ah I misread that sorry, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primed coordinates are just "dummy" coordinates over which we integrate the contributions to the electric field at a fixed observation point $\vec r$ from a differential charge, $dq=\rho(\vec r')\,dV'$, at $\vec r'$.

The distance between to fixed observation point $\vec r$ and the differential charge at $\vec r'$ is $|\vec r-\vec r'|$ and the unit vector from the charge to the observation point is $\frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{|\vec r-\vec r'|}$.

The contribution to the electric field, $d\vec E(\vec r)$, from a differential charge $dq=\rho(\vec r')\,dV'$, at $\vec r'$ is given by

$$\begin{align}
d\vec E(\vec r)&=\frac{dq}{4\pi \epsilon_0 |\vec r-\vec r'|^2}\,\,\underbrace{\left(\frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{|\vec r-\vec r'|}\right)}_{=\hat u(\vec r-\vec r')}\\\\
&=\frac{\rho(\vec r')\,\hat u(\vec r-\vec r')}{4\pi \epsilon_0 |\vec r-\vec r'|^2}\,dV'
\end{align}$$

Then we sum the contributions by integrating over the volume $V$ that contains all of the charge to obtain'

$$\begin{align}
\vec E(\vec r)&=\iiint_V d\vec E(\vec r)\\\\
&=\iiint_V\frac{\rho(\vec r')\,\hat u(\vec r-\vec r')}{4\pi \epsilon_0 |\vec r-\vec r'|^2}\,dV'
\end{align}$$

Comment: This is great! Thank you!! Is there any difference between how you wrote the unit vector with $u(r - r')$ vs just $u(r')$? Sorry, I can't find the right MathJax symbols for this :)

Comment: First, pleased to hear this is useful.  And you're quite welcome.  That unit vector depends on both the location of the observation point and the location of the charge element at $\vec r'$.

Comment: Thanks again. It's strange though because the fact that the unit vector depends on both locations makes it make sense for the vectors to be subtracted, so how come the textbook can write $u(r')$ (like in the figure in the original question) and still get the correct vector direction? It says previously that just $u$ alone is defined to be the unit vector from $r'$ to $r$ so I wasn't sure if the same idea would apply here.

Comment: I an not sure as to why the text book writes it that way.  A better and more explicit way to write it is $\frac{\vec r-\vec r'}{|\vec r-\vec r'|}$.

Comment: Thank you once again - it's so great to have input from an expert in this field even though my question is relatively basic :)

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 0):

$r$ is a radius vector (the one where you evaluate the field) and $r'$ just another (covers all locations in $V$). You could use any other symbol instead of $r'$. The total (vector) field is the sum of the (vector) fields generated by the individual charges.